# Encrypted SQLite database can't be opened with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, encryption

My SQLite Connection string looks like:

```
        string conn = "Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;";
        if (passphrase != null)
        {
            conn += "Page Size=1024;Password=" + passphrase + "";
        }

        _mDbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(conn);
        _mDbConnection.Open();
```

This works so far and the password is obviously correct. ;-)
But whenever i want to run a query then i get the error:

```
SQLite error (26): file is not a database
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>dbtool.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.106.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139</ExceptionType><Message>file is not a database
file is not a database</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String&amp;amp; strRemain)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

The encrypted database file can however be openend fine with other tools like `DB Browser for SQLite`.
The unencrypted version also works fine with System.Data.SQLite.

Comment: What was the database encrypted with? The encrypted edition of SQLite? If so, are you using the same version of SQLite to open it?

Comment: @JonathanWood It was encrypted with a recent version of the tool `DB Browser for SQLite` which uses `SQLCipher Version 3.15.2`.

Comment: And you're using the same tool to open it?

Comment: Well if I use that tool, then it works. However when I want to use C# code to open it via the `System.Data.SQLite` library, then it doesnt.

Comment: [SQLitePCL.raw](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/blob/master/README.md) project has native x86 and x64 dlls for sqlcipher. You can try to replace native dlls used by System.Data.Sqlite by the ones in that project.

Comment: @bamanow I'm actually doing just that right now. Any advice on where to replace the native DLL? Using the AES256 encryption [found here](https://github.com/rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption)

Comment: I use SQLite.NET, not System.Data.Sqlite. But as a guess, find location of sqlite3.dll in your project folder. Replace it with dlls from the package I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) encrypts the entire database. That includes all headers, data definitions and anything else. A database encrypted this way is completely jibberish unless you are using the SQLite Encryption Extension. Otherwise, I would expect an error saying the database is not recognized as a database.

So, I'm not familiar with *DB Browser for SQLite*, but if it is using that extension to encrypt the database, you will only be able to read the database if you are using the SQLite Encryption Extension.

Since the extension costs about $2,000, it's a fair assumption that `System.Data.SQLite` is not working with this extension.

You will need this extension to read and write encrypted databases.

Comment: I see, that would make sense. Are there any ways to encrypt/decrypt with `System.Data.SQLite` only?

Comment: @oleole: You could write your own encryption code. But you would only be encrypting the individual fields, such as just encrypting strings before you save them and decrypting them after you read them. It would not encrypt the entire file like SQLite Encryption Extension does. So it would be more work and not as secure.

Comment: It IS possible.  Not sure when but System.Data.SQLite does allow you to encrypt the database.  The issue I have is that once I encrypt my SQLite db I am no longer able to access it even when supplying the password using 3rd part tools.  I am using SQLiteStudio however once I encrypt a db using my .NET app I am unable to open it with any tool other than my own app.